# 4 Pin Cyrstal Oscillator Pinout to connect to Xi and Xo of CH340G

Tags: oscillator, schematics, clock, crystal, pinout

I need to connect a crystal oscillator to CH340G USB TTL converter, the oscillator I have is 3N12000G33YC with pinout and test circuit shown. It has 4 pins which I am unfamiliar with, I only know there is 3 or 2 pin oscillators, this is new to me.

I am unsure how to connect it to Xi and Xo of the CH340.

I am also unsure if this crystal needs the two 22pf capacitors as usual with 2 pin crystals.

The last picture shows a connection I have seen online but I am unsure of the possibility of that.

CH340G datasheet crystal connection
[image: CH340G datasheet crystal connection]

CH340G datasheet pin description
[image: CH340G datasheet pin description]

Crystal datasheet pin description
[image: Crystal datasheet pin description]

Crystal datasheet test circuit
[image: Crystal datasheet test circuit]

I have seen this suggestion on forums
[image: I have seen this suggestion on forums]

Comment: The circuit you show is for when you're using a bare crystal with the microcontroller; what you have appears to be a *crystal oscillator*, which is a crystal along with other stuff to make it oscillate. Generally you can use either with a microcontroller, but the oscillator will just be connected to a single pin.

Comment: What about the other pin of the microcontroller "Xo"? leave it unconnected? Pull it down? Ground it? What about the enable and VCC, do I just tie them to vcc and assert the enable?

Comment: Probably leave it unconnected. Read the details of your microcontroller and oscillators' datasheets.

Comment: They're both in chinese for the most part

Comment: Anyway to just wire it up like a 2 pin cyrstal with external 22pf caps?

Comment: Better learn to read Chinese, then. I strongly recommend getting parts that you can get a datasheet in a language you're fluent in whenever possible.

Comment: No. You can't do that with a crystal oscillator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from the content of [this translated CH340G Datasheet](https://static.efetividade.net/img/ch340g-datasheet-34852.pdf) (page 4):

"*During operation CH340 requires a 12MHz clock signal present at XI pin. Generally this clock
signal is provided by connecting a 12MHz crystal resonator and load capacitors between XI
and XO pins, and the built-in crystal resonator will provide the required clock signal. **When
using an external oscillator feed the clock signal into XI pin, and leave XO pin unconnected.***"

You need to connect the output (*OUT*) of your crystal oscillator to  the XI pin on the CH340G and leave the XO pin unconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Out goes to XI for input only.

XO is the inverted output used internally or shared depending on design.